# I need help with fixing this query please!

Tags: query, sql-server-2017

I need to figure out what is wrong with this query. I get this error when running the query: "Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

```
SELECT p.first_name, 
    p.last_name, 
    p.date_of_birth, 
    REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(PT.med_rec_nbr,0,' ')),' ',0), 
    PE.enc_timestamp, 
    PD.document_desc,PD.template_file, 
    PE.rendering_provider_id, 
    PM.description, 
    FX.fax_status, 
    FX.to_fax, 
    FX.to_name, 
    isnull(R.efRule,0) 

FROM patient_encounter PE 
INNER JOIN patient_documents PD 
    ON PE.enc_id=PD.enc_id
INNER JOIN person P 
    ON PE.person_id=p.person_id
INNER JOIN patient PT 
    ON PE.person_id=PT.person_id 
    AND PE.practice_id=PT.practice_id
INNER JOIN provider_mstr PM 
    ON PE.rendering_provider_id=PM.provider_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT to_name, to_fax, doc_id,fax_status from fax_result
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fax_to_name, 'TASKED', document_id, 'SENT' 
    FROM NGPlugin_Auto_Fax_Hist_ 
    WHERE job_type = 'T'
) FX 
    ON PD.document_id=FX.doc_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FAX.provider_id,FA.document_name,
        '1' as 'efRule' 
    FROM NGPlugin_Auto_Fax_Assign_ FA 
    INNER JOIN NGPlugin_AF_Assign_Xref_ FAX 
        ON FA.rule_id=FAX.rule_id
) R 
    ON PE.rendering_provider_id=R.provider_id 
    AND PD.template_file=R.document_name
```

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Which database system and version?... Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. We'll be having a hard time guessing without knowing the table definitions (DDL). If possible add them to the question by hitting [edit] and adding the missing information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can't help you without knowing your tables structures.

What might be wrong, is either:

1. You're joining on fields of two different types, eg. maybe patient_encounter.enc_id is a GUID and patient_documents.enc_id is a varchar or vice versa, or template_file is a GUID while document_name is a varchar, etc.

OR

2. Problem is in UNION if types from fax_result are not matching types from NGPlugin_Auto_Fax_Hist_